# Cache does not work under Kohana PHP Framework on Linux server

Tags: php, apache, caching, memcached, kohana

I have a strange problem. I wanted to enable cache on my webpage. I have installed memcache module on my laptop (windows) and production server (suse). Everything works fine on my computer and everything seems to work on server when I paste this code:

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

var_dump($get_result);

?>
```

But when I am using Kohana on production it does not save cache. I do not know why. Maybe permissions or smth? My folder application/cache has 777 chmod.

```
  memcached-tool localhost:11211 stats
#localhost:11211   Field       Value
         accepting_conns           1
               auth_cmds           0
             auth_errors           0
                   bytes           0
              bytes_read    21713253
           bytes_written         513
              cas_badval           0
                cas_hits           0
              cas_misses           0
               cmd_flush           0
                 cmd_get           9
                 cmd_set           0
               cmd_touch           0
             conn_yields           0
   connection_structures           6
        curr_connections           5
              curr_items           0
               decr_hits           0
             decr_misses           0
             delete_hits           0
           delete_misses           9
       evicted_unfetched           0
               evictions           0
       expired_unfetched           0
                get_hits           0
              get_misses           9
              hash_bytes      524288
       hash_is_expanding           0
        hash_power_level          16
               incr_hits           0
             incr_misses           0
                libevent 2.0.10-stable
          limit_maxbytes  4294967296
     listen_disabled_num           0
                     pid        8014
            pointer_size          64
               reclaimed           0
            reserved_fds          20
           rusage_system    0.035994
             rusage_user    0.035994
                 threads           4
                    time  1485509197
       total_connections          15
             total_items           0
              touch_hits           0
            touch_misses           0
                  uptime        1244
                 version      1.4.13
```

Regards